# Converting string into JSON from MySQL, Unexpected token N

Tags: mysql, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am executing an MYSQL query using AWS RDS. The table structure stored in the database returns the result something like this (sample):

```
patient_id | calculation_time | calculation_parameters | comprehensive

4b53bb2567 | 12:19:04 | {"a":1, "b":2} | [{"label": "label1", "cat4_cnt":{"status":"critical", "count": 2},"cat3_cnt":{"status":"high", "count":8},"median":1.05}, {"label": "label2", "cat4_cnt":{"status":"critical", "count":4}, "cat3_cnt":{"status": "high", "count":3}, "median":1.25}]
```

My AWS `handler.js` file sends the response in the way:

```
..... //
    const response = {
          body: {
            statusCode: 200,
            data: comprehensive,
          }
        };
    
        callback(null, response);
// .......
```

After executing the handler, the final data received in postman is of the form:

```
{
    "body": {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "data": "[{\"label\": \"label1\", \"cat4_cnt\":{\"status\":\"critical\", \"count\": 2},\"cat3_cnt\":{\"status\":\"high\", \"count\":8}, \"median\":1.05}, {\"label\": \label2\", \"cat4_cnt\":{\"status\":\"critical\", \"count\":4}, \"cat3_cnt\":{\"status\": \"high\", \"count\":3}, \"median\":1.25}]",
    }
}
```

What I required, is to convert the `data` received into a proper `JSON`. I simply did(in `handler.js` itself):

```
..... //
        const response = {
              body: {
                statusCode: 200,
                data: JSON.parse(comprehensive),
              }
            };
        
            callback(null, response);
// .......
```

Which throws an error:

```
{
    "body": {
        "message": "Unexpected token N in JSON at position 30",
        "data": null
    }
}
```

The `typeof` data returned from the database that I need to convert is a `string` (checked with `console.log(typeof comprehensive)` already)

I know many questions are already available on the same topic, but doesn't seems to work for me. Any help to convert the database response into proper JSON is appreciated.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What is the value of 'comprehensive' when you get that error?

Comment: The value of  'comprehensive' is the array of objects returned from the MySQL query (in the form of string), as already mentioned in the start

Comment: I know what it's supposed to be  but that wouldn't give you this error.  What is the *actual* value in your debugger when it throws that error?

Comment: comprehesive = `[{\"label\": \"label1\", \"cat4_cnt\":{\"status\":\"critical\", \"count\": 2},\"cat3_cnt\":{\"status\":\"high\", \"count\":8},........` is the actual value that needs to be converted into JSON but throws error on doing `JSON.parse(comprehensive)` on it.

Comment: That's the value that needs converting, but is that what the variable 'comprehensive' is set to when the error occurs? Because if it is, that's not a string and JSON.parse() takes a string.

Comment: Have you read my question completely? I have already mentioned that I checked the type of variable `comprehensive` already, and it does return its type as a 'string'

Comment: and what is the value of that String when the error is thrown?

Comment: Because the string is valid JSON and does not throw the error when sent to JSON.parse() https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=URVr0o68iw

Comment: @JeffUK I understand that and already tried that. But currently, I am stuck in the issue with reference to the MySQL database. If you can suggest, to convert or insert the data into the MySQL data into a proper string format so that it can be parsed afterwards?